# How can I ask the question according to description below?

Tags: questions

1) I want to ask about the room which was the end point for the book (e.g. To what room the book was taken?)

assertion:
The book was taken **to that room**

question:

Where **was** the book taken

2) I want to ask about origin place, from what room the book was taken to this room

assertion:
The book was taken **to that room**

question:

Where the book **was** taken?

3) Compound 'wh' questions

from the first example:

Do you know where the book **was** taken?

from the second example:

Do you know where the book **was** taken? *(exactly the same)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the word order, as in question 2, it ceases to be a question.

The easiest way to specify exactly what you want to know is to use a preposition:

> 1) Where was the book taken **to**?
>   2) Where was the book taken **from**? 
>   3a) Do you know where the book was taken **to**?
>   3b) Do you know where the book was taken **from**?

Some people may complain about the [dangling preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) in these sentences, bur really there is nothing wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition.

Comment: I think what OP needs to become better informed about is the matter of *subject/verb inversion* in ***actual questions*** (but not in ***wh- clauses***), rather than anything to do with dangling prepositions (which can easily be avoided with *Do you know **from where** it was taken?*, for example, though I see no reason to avoid the alternative either).

Comment: ...of course, there's always *Do you know **whence** it was taken?*, but I suspect even many *native* speakers might misunderstand that and tell you where it *ended up*, not where it *started from*.